# How can I have every key on a standard keyboard make a Thunk when key is struck

Tags: keyboard

Is there a way to make the keys make a "THUNK" noise when each key is struck?  I have use of only my left hand and need the auditory feedback when i strike a key.  When I upgraded to 16.04 (LTS) the python click program that a colleague wrote around 2007 suddenly quit working.  For months I have been using an emulator that outputs typewriter clicks.  I would appreciate help   in getting my solid thunk feedback going again.

Comment: If you can, please post the original Python program as well. There are several Python fans here who might be happy to fix it.

Comment: Pretty cool idea using python.  Not that this is an answer but have you considered purchasing a mechanical keyboard?  That wouldn't be dependent on software and imho a better keyboard in general.

Comment: You can try Tickeys which I believe is also a python app. [http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/keyboard-sounds-linux-when-typing](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/keyboard-sounds-linux-when-typing). That page shows how to install. It has several different sounds you can use when typing. The bottom of the page also has links to two other apps Qwertickle and Linux Typewriter is Tickeys isn't what you want.

Comment: I haven't used this site for awhile, so apologies for any screwups.  --First, to muru, after finding the src in ~/bin, I remember how convoluted this is.  The program is named "keyclick" and is at least three directories deep.  Note thhat the fellow who wrote it seemed to fell that I was nagging him... even tho it was based on a program he had written for his young soon.  I'd guess that this version 0.1.1 toook him at least an entire day.  That is a lot to ask of somebody I know only via email.  Is there a way I can send this as a czvf tarball?

Comment: To #2, yes, I have owned 2 clicky k'boards, but my daughter spilled water and juice on both when she was a kid so I've gone Low-Cost.

Comment: -- Well, folllowing a *zoo* iof instructions, the tickeys finally works.  I have to write a section in my  ~/.HowTo page, but for now, thanks to y'all!    &GrannySez

Comment: @user975156 posting the script as a gist or project on Github would be best.

Comment: Well, here is the latest, gents.  Someone from launchpad suggested that I put my "keyclick-0.1.1.tar" bunch of python files into dropbox.com .  This I did.  But to share this tarball,   when I typed    muru , the website complained.  So,  if you--anyone on this list-- could email me his address, perhaps you, &muru , could send your email and I'll type it into the dropbox space and you can grab it.    -----Note that my sysadmin found  a workaround and I chown'd the directories and files.  No luck.  TIA  kline {at} thought {dot} org .

Comment: Forgot:  time/ date UTC  was  approx 01:45 hours.

Comment: Well, I owe BillBillBillBill from China for getting me the *entire* Tickeys source.  I googled the full instructions to build the python [and C] binary.  --Here, I'lll  fess up to my poor eyesight and other failings.]  BUT, finally, I typed "tickeys" and heard a cool THUNK  with each keystroke.